# How to round an float value and convert it into NSInteger value in the iPhone SDK?

Tags: objective-c

I need to round a float value and convert it into an `NSInteger` value.

For example:

```
float f = 90.909088;
```

I want the result to be 91. How to get rid of this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One of the following C math functions might work for you:

- double ceil(double)
- double floor(double)
- double nearbyint(double)
- double rint(double)
- double round(double)
- long int lrint(double)
- long int lround(double)
- long long int llrint(double)
- long long int llround(double)
- double trunc(double)

To get more documentation, open a terminal session and type (for example)

```
man lround
```

I pick lround as an example because I think that is the one you want.

Comment: Many math functions have float versions as well. Just add an f. For example: floorf().

Answer (score 22):

A quick round and cast will work for negative values as well as positives:

```
NSInteger intValue = (NSInteger) roundf(f);
```

Comment: This answer should be the top rated one

Answer (score 4):

Do

```
f = floor(f + 0.5)
```

before the integer conversion.

Comment: when I done with this if I pass the value as 315 it was converted as 32.I need to remain it same as 315 if it doesn't have any decimal points.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
float f = 90.909088;
NSNumber *myNumber = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:(f+0.5)];
NSInteger myInt = [myNumber intValue];
```

Comment: when I done with this if I pass the value as 315 it was converted as 32.I need to remain it same as 315 if it doesn't have any decimal points